# PHP - Parsing nested JSON array values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have hit a wall and I am not sure what is causing this. I am parsing a JSON file and creating variables. All the ones that are not nested in arrays work great. These two below are not though and I am not sure why. $hail var value shows for both the hail and the $wind var and I am completely puzzled as to why.

Here is a snippet of the code to create the variable from the value.

```
     $hail = isset($currFeature['properties']['parameters']['hailSize'][0]);
     $wind = isset($currFeature['properties']['parameters']['windGust'][0]);
```

Here is how it is outputted and displayed in the HTML which it displays but shows $hail for both var.

```
 <div class="alerts-description"> HAZARDS<br /><? if (isset($hail)) {echo $hail . '" Hail';} ?><br /> <? if (isset($wind)) {echo $wind . '" MPH Winds';} ?></div>
```

Example of array as both hailSize and windGust is nested under parameters and both [0]

```
                    [response] => Avoid
                    [parameters] => Array
                        (
                            [hailSize] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 0.50
                                )

                            [windGust] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 70
                                )

                            [VTEC] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => /O.NEW.KFWD.FA.W.0008.170813T1318Z-170813T1615Z/
                                )

                            [EAS-ORG] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => WXR
                                )
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong or am missing?

EDIT: Link to example code just hit the "Run it" button"

http://rextester.com/EELE62798

-Thanks!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: What is your output for both `$hail` and `$wind`? Considering you're using `isset()` in the variable assignment (in addition to the conditional), you should only be getting a `true/false` output from your `echo $hail` and `echo $wind`.

Comment: PHP 7

@ObsidianAge that is a very good point and catch which lead to this question from earlier for this exact reason. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743860/php-isset-vs-empty?noredirect=1#comment78453243_45743860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $hail = isset($currFeature['properties']['parameters']['hailSize'][0]);
```

The above code will generate a variable with the value `true` or `false`. It will never have the value from your data.

The following PHP7 code is a possible solution.

```
<?php

$json = '{"properties":{"parameters":{"hailSize":[0.50],"windGust":[70]}}}';
$currFeature = json_decode($json, true);


$hail = $currFeature['properties']['parameters']['hailSize'][0] ?? null;
$wind = $currFeature['properties']['parameters']['windGust'][0] ?? null;

// check specifically for null 
if ( $hail !== null ) {
    echo $hail . '" Hail'. PHP_EOL;
}
// check specifically for null 
if ( $wind !== null ) {
    echo $wind . '" MPH Winds'. PHP_EOL;
}

if ( empty($currFeature['properties']['parameters']['windGust'][1]) ) {
    echo "empty also works to check for missing data\n";
}

if ( ! isset($currFeature['properties']['parameters']['windGust'][1]) ) {
    echo "isset to check for missing data\n";
}
```

If you run it on the command line you will get the following output:

```
0.5" Hail
70" MPH Winds
empty also works to check for missing data
isset to check for missing data
```

Comment: Thanks, the isset() stems from this question I had earlier to try to tackle a different issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743860/php-isset-vs-empty?noredirect=1#comment78453243_45743860 that ['hailSize'] or ['windGust'] key is not always outputted in the JSON. So I needed something to tackle that issue if it's not outputted to prevent throwing the error of undefined when it is not in the JSON file. When I did that I now have this issue.

Comment: You can use ??, isset, empty and array_key_exists to check for the existence of the data.

Comment: This is precisely what I was thinking was the solution. Setting `isset()` on the variable assignment made no sense. This is definitely the way that I would recommend going about it =]

Comment: This method throws "Array to string conversion" error unless there is something I am missing. Here is demo code example... http://rextester.com/EELE62798

Comment: I ran it on rextester and local and I don't see any such error.

Comment: Did you notice something missing from that link? The code you posted. 

http://c2n.me/3N1UItl.png

http://rextester.com/WUVF42925

Check those links

Comment: `$hail = $currFeature['properties']['parameters']['hailSize'] ?? null;`
should be   `$hail = $currFeature['properties']['parameters']['hailSize'][0] ?? null;`